# Titulo Datatable

Tags: datatables

Me gustaría poder ponerle un titulo a una tabla de datatables  para que al imprimirla, pasarla a excel o pdf, aparezca el titulo el titulo aparezca.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable();
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.0/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.3/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.40/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.3/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.40/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/2.5.0/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.3/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table id="tblAcciones"  class="hover cell-border row-border display compact"  cellspacing="0" width="100%">
     
          
          <table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Puesto</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
                <th>City</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>email</th>
               
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>5421</td>
                <td>t.nixon@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
          
            <tr>
                <td>Zenaida Frank</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>$125,250</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>7439</td>
                <td>z.frank@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Zorita Serrano</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>$115,000</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>4389</td>
                <td>z.serrano@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jennifer Acosta</td>
                <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>$75,650</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>3431</td>
                <td>j.acosta@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Donna Snider</td>
                <td>Customer Support</td>
                <td>$112,000</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>4226</td>
                <td>d.snider@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Extn.</th>
                <th>E-mail</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estimado, para poner titulo a los reportes del plugin a tu código debes agregar lo siguiente:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').DataTable();
           buttons:[{
           text: "Exportar a PDF", //Título del botón
           messageTop: "Título de mi PDF " //Coloca el título dentro del PDF

      }]
    } );
```